# Error in \subfloat

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

I checked online a lot and I still cannot see the error. I would greatly appreciate any help.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letter]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
        \centering
  \subfloat[Argentina]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{GCF_ARG}}
  \subfloat[Brasil]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{GCF_BRA}}\\
  \subfloat[M\'exico]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{GCF_MEX}}
  \subfloat[China]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{GCF_CHN}}\\
   \subfloat[India]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{GCF_IND}}
  \subfloat[Rusia]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{GCF_RUS}}\\
   \subfloat[Sudafrica]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{GCF_ZAF}}
  \subfloat[USA]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{GCF_USA}}\\
  \subfloat[Indonesia]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{GCF_IDN}}
  \subfloat[Turqu\'ia]{\label{fig:tur}\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{GCF_TUR}}\\
 \caption{Ciclos econ\'omicos de Formaci\'on Bruta de Capital (GCF)}
  \label{rbc1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get the error 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.316   \subfloat
                 [Argentina]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{GCF_ARG}}
?

Thank you.

Comment: Just to let you know I do not get that error. And after replacing your figures by `example-image-a` your code compiles without problems on my TeXLive 2018 installation.

Comment: Given code is compiling well. Try in latest version.

Comment: Even the very first release of the `subfig` package had offered `\subfloat` so I assume you are using a local copy of `subfig.sty` in your document folder which does not contain the "real" subfig package. Or your TeX installation is erroneous. Could you please insert a `\listfiles` at the top of the document and show us the output?

Comment: Hello, I inserted \listfiles at the top of the page. I cannot open the output; it says it is already open in another application (I checked and it is not the case). I still keep getting the same error message. Can you please provide the correct subfig.sty file?

Comment: I got the subfig.sty file from http://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/texmacros/subfig.sty

Comment: @SupratimDasGupta That's a bogus `subfig.sty` that has nothing to do with the “official” one on CTAN. It's quite likely that if you get rid of the bogus package, you'll be OK.